How to statically check type of an expression without using a variable?
Say I have some function whose arguments are not typed (or at least not typed specifically enough for my use case) and some interface I have defined myself
// f is some function from a JS library
const f = (x: any) => console.log(x);

interface SpecificObject {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

We can do this:
const tmpVar: SpecificObject = {a: ""};
f(tmpVar);

And the compiler correctly gives an error because it statically sees that the key b is missing from our literal.
But this creates an unnecessary temporary variable tmpVar. How do I get this same type checking behavior without using an extra variable?
I have tried:
f({a: ""} as SpecificObject);

But this does not give an error. It seems that as is more like a forced type assertion, rather than one that will be checked like the variable typing above.

You could use the satisfies operator as shown here. Does that fully address the question? If so then I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Can you not add type information for the function via a declaration file so that the type is checked without any special annotation at the call site at all?

@T.J.Crowder If the function is something like JSON.stringify and I am calling it on various different interfaces, I wouldn't want to decleare the function itself to take that specific type.

@jcalz Yes, the satisfies operator is exactly what I was looking for, thank you

You can use the satisfies operator be sort of like a type-safe as. It doesn't unsafely narrow the type of the expression before it (although it provides a context which might affect its inferred type), so you'll get a warning if it doesn't satisfy the relevant type:
f({ a: "" } satisfies SpecificObject); // error!
//          ~~~~~~~~~
//   Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; }'

f({ a: "", b: "" } satisfies SpecificObject); // okay

Playground link to code
